# How do sites have login api's without file extensions?

Tags: php, api-design

I have a simple php script for hwid checks on a c# app i made it just checks if the hwid and email match and sends it to the app again. But i've looked through websites to see how i should add more security and i've come across multiple where they are sending POST requests to `www.site.com/api/login` and there's no file extension. how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using for your backend
if you are using framework like laravel or etc
you can define your own route to handle the url request
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

if you are using native you can use .htaccess for that
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32140158/9590296

Comment: uploading the .htaccess with the code in it to the website root worked flawlessly! thanks :)