# hiding php extension without removing the .php in the actual files

Tags: php, .htaccess

this is the most common way of hiding php extensions using htacess, but this only works when the actual file does not have an extension, for instance a file like `index.php` has to be changed to `index` this is not suitable in development mode, now is there a way to hide the extension and still maintain the file name intact?

```
  # Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

here is my file structure

#### my website [root folder]

- index.php
- about.php

#### views folder[inside the root]

- index.php
- about.php

Comment: This should be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32140158/12232340

Comment: In that answer says you have two ways to do that! 1. Way is htaccess file and 2.way is ISS. And there isn’t another way I think. I wouldn’t even try to open a file doesn’t have an extension, any security program will take  that file as a malware and dangerous. I don’t understand why would you want to have a file without extension.

Comment: Apache won’t know how to read a file without an extension and will attempt to download file as an unknown file, and firewall will block file and warn pc users. so, htaccess file tells to Apache your file is a .php file but extension is hiden and Apache reads file as a .php file, Php.net is saying hide your php extensions, not saying remove them. you must have misunderstood.

Comment: No offence, but you need to think for yourself... hiding *.html extensions is exactly the same, but you just hide the *.php in addition to the HTML. Stack Overflow is for assistance with your code, we aren't a code writing service.

Comment: IF @lSerni hadn't explained it, i don think i would've gotten any assistance. What you did was close the question, u didnt understand that i wanted a better explanation for my code. I got assisted though, and that's the most important thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you post does exactly what you say you want. You have a "index.php" file on the file system, and your URL is something like "www.mysite.com/index" (no .php extension in the URL).

```
RewriteEngine on
# The requested filename "/index" is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# There is a file on the file system named as the request, with extension .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# If all of the above is true, pretend that the ".php" file had been called
# by rewriting the request appending .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

You do not need to rename "index.php" as "index".

If you **also** want to prevent access if .php is specified, place this rule **before** the one above. Now, "mysite/index" will work, "mysite/index.php" will not.

```
# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "\.php$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Please note that there are several other ways in which someone might realize your site uses PHP, and the php-to-404 rule doesn't make much sense.

Comment: alright, i get it now